# Using all_of with a collection of lambda functions?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

As it is currently, this code works and checks that each value matches all of the filters in the FilterCollection, is it possible to use all_of (any_of, none_of, etc.) in such a scenario to compact this function down a bit more?

```
template<typename T>
bool filter(const T& filters, int val)
{
    // Can use std::all_of() somehow?
    for (auto filter : filters)
    {
        if (!filter(val))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    using FilterContainer = std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>>;
    FilterContainer lxFilters;
    lxFilters.emplace_back([&](int val) { return val % 5 == 0; });
    lxFilters.emplace_back([&](int val) { return val >= 10; });
    lxFilters.emplace_back([&](int val) { return val <= 100; });

    using FilterResults = std::vector<bool>;
    FilterResults filteredValues;
    filteredValues.push_back(filter(lxFilters, 5)); // False
    filteredValues.push_back(filter(lxFilters, 10)); // True
    filteredValues.push_back(filter(lxFilters, 50)); // True
    filteredValues.push_back(filter(lxFilters, 100)); // True
    filteredValues.push_back(filter(lxFilters, 42)); // False

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible in the following way:

```
template<typename T>
bool filter(const T& filters, int val)
{
    return std::all_of(std::begin(filters), std::end(filters),
     [val](const auto& func) 
     {
         return func(val);
     });
}
```

Comment: To compare to the original code, the params of the lambda names the predicate "func" which in this case would be the element we're operating on from the collection range (like if it had been `const auto & filter` instead of `const auto & func`)?

Comment: @AaronStackpole Yes, func lambda parameter is the element of "filters" collection

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return false for any filter that will not be satisfied then you need to use *std::any_of*

```
template<typename T>
bool filter(const T& filters, const int val)
{
    return std::any_of(std::begin(filters), std::end(filters),
        [val](const auto& filter){return !filter(val);});
}
```